# Android UI design using PSD and dynamic data

Tags: android, psd

I am trying to create good looking UI for an android application. After researching online, I found that PSD files are a great way to get good UI/UX. Also, I found that PSD files cannot be directly used, but should be converted to png/jpg and then can be used as backgrounds in UI.

But I have a question on how to handle dynamic data which comes from various data sources on the android UI so that it stitches well with the other static data/content which is available in the UI (from png/jpg backgrounds)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you give a scenario/example with regards to your question? I cannot clearly understand your question.

Comment: Hi. Let me explain, I have to design an android app. I have taken good PSD files from Internet whose static content can be changed using Adobe Photoshop. Once changed, I can save these as png/jpg and can use as backgrounds in my app. But I am trying to see how can i make my dynamic content compatible with the static images in background

Comment: i guess make your layout dynamic. do you want to make the background adjust to the contents of the app?

Comment: I think your concern is to make your images adapt on different devices(size and resolution) and not on the contents since contents(data) are most of the times dynamic. In that case, you should consider reading the documentation on supporting multiple devices and using NinePatch.

Answer (score 0):

PSD is just Photoshop format. It's not connecter to bad or good design at all. I guess you should read tutorial first. Start with this [one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

This is good [library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for showing images from device and url.

And I think you need to continue research. Start with basic

Comment: Hi. Totally agree with you, But using PSD, I can create better UI since I can use lot of the already created elements from PSD files.